# Facing issue with ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose. Scrim color is not animating while opening and closing of sheet and white line on right corner

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, material-components-android, bottom-sheet

I am using ModalBottomSheet but I am facing two issues:

1. There is a white line on the right corner of the scrim
2. The scrim color is not animating while opening and closing of ModalBottomSheet

[image]

[image]

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Button(onClick = {
    showBottomSheet = true
}) {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "")
    Text("Show bottom sheet")
}

if (showBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { showBottomSheet = false },
        sheetState = sheetState,
        dragHandle = { Text(text = "") },
        scrimColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.63f),
        containerColor = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier.height(280.dp),
        windowInsets = WindowInsets(0,0,0,0)
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "This is a bottom sheet")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                    if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                        showBottomSheet = false
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Hide bottom sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Compose are you using? Your code worked fine for me with BOM 2023.10.01

Comment: Did you add it inside a `Scaffold` or `Surface`?

Comment: No, it's not inside `Scaffold` or `Surface`

Comment: I am using the same BOM version. These are the dependencies that I am using: 
`implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0") implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2") implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01")) implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui") implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")`

Comment: `implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")`

Comment: `androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")`

Comment: @Philio the scrim color is animating on your side?  does the scrim color move from fully transparent to less transparent slowly and vice versa?

on my side the color just converts from fully transparent to directly less transparent with no animation. like the scrim color is not going out or coming in smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, worked fine for me, but I used `Scaffold`. The Material theme doesn't work properly if you don't use it or `Surface`. Give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256643/discussion-between-m-sarmad-qadeer-and-philio).